# Is message-body required when sending error response status code 4xx-5xx?

Tags: ajax, http, http-status-codes

When sending a response status code of 4xx-5xx in response to a GET or POST **Ajax** request, is the message-body required?

I'm just learning Ajax. For regular requests, I send a nice HTML page for the user to see. But in the case of Ajax requests, it will be ignored anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) states that:

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client
>   seems to have erred. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
>   server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the error
>   situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.
>
> Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in
>   which the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of
>   performing the request. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
>   server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the error
>   situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

It's not a MUST, so you may if you want to be nice, but it's not required. Keep in mind, though, that sometimes a 200 (or 204) response is even more appropriate  than 4xx or 5xx (even in your own ajax). This may help you distinguish between errors on server side and error codes that you intentionally send to client side.

For completeness sake, a quote from [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt):

> 1. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there    may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>      particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>      carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

Comment: I do plan to use a 200 status code for 'known' errors so I can use the data object. But there are cases when my script outputs a standard error. If the Ajax fails, my plan is to output the errorThrown rather than trying to parse jqXHR for info. I also plan to check for status code 200 in the fail callback and output a generic fail message in that case.

Comment: 2xx indicates that a request was ACCEPTED which is not your case. If you use them for this then you are creating your own proprietary protocol which is actually tunneling HTTP. You will also loose HTTP features. e.g. cacheability  because you are breaking uniform interface.

Comment: @filip26 it is appropriate for POST, because response is to "describe the results of the action". GET returning an error object on 200 would mean that error object is associated with the request, which is also a valid situation (and may even be cacheable).

Comment: @Lyth you are wrong, it's not appropriate. There is no such statement in RFC. You just invent it ....